# How to inject mocked object by jmockit to a spring managed object with @Transactional method?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, transactional, jmockit

I am writing a TestNG test case in a spring project and use jmockit to mock dependencies. I encounter a problem, that is I cannot use Deencapsulation.setField to set dependency to a spring-managed object contain a @Transactional method, the error is:

> No instance field of name "dataLogManager" found in class java.lang.reflect.Proxy

My sample code listed here,

Test case:

```
public class QueueManagerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired  
    private QueueManager queueManager;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired  
    private TransInfoManager transInfoManager;

    @Autowired
    private Generator generator;

    @Autowired
    private MessageDTOFactoryBean messageDTOFactoryBean;

    @Test(description="單元測試：寫入一筆Data資料，非邊界情況下（無待處理筆數）")
    public void writeControlMessage(            
        @Mocked final TransInfoManager transInfoManager,
        @Mocked final DataManager dataManager,
        @Mocked final DataLogManager dataLogManager
        ) {
    ....
        Deencapsulation.setField(queueManager, "dataLogManager", dataLogManager);
        Deencapsulation.setField(queueManager, "dataManager", dataManager);
        Deencapsulation.setField(queueManager, "transInfoManager", transInfoManager);
    ....
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public interface QueueManager {         

    @Transactional
    MessageDTO putDataIntoQueue(MessageDTO message);

}
```

Anybody knows how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to test is some specific class implementing the `QueueManager` interface, then a solution is simply to instantiate the class directly in the test, rather than using Spring for that.

The reason for the exception is that Spring actually creates a *proxy* class instance for the `queueManager` field, intended to decorate the real implementation (the proxy object delegates every method call to another object, which would be an instance of an application class actually implementing the `QueueManager` interface). The proxy class does not contain a field named "dataLogManager", so that's why `Deencapsulation.setField(...)` can't find it.

If the first solution I mentioned is not applicable, you can still let Spring do the instantiation, provided it also inject the fields inside the `queueManager` object. To mock the class implementing `DataLogManager` (and other interfaces), use `@Capturing` instead of (or in addition to) `@Mocked`; this will instruct JMockit to extend mocking to all implementation classes.